# how to search for entries where a custom field is either not present or is empty

Tags: search, custom-field

Some of my entries have the optional plaintext field `myCustomField`. I want to retrieve all entries except those where `myCustomField` is filled out.

I can get all entries that have an empty `myCustomField`

```
craft.entries({
    myCustomField: ':empty:',
})
```

but that doesn't include entries that don't have the field `myCustomField`.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that this *is* possible for lightswitch fields:

`craft.entries.myLightswitchField(':empty:')`

aka

```
craft.entries({
    myLightswitchField: ':empty:'
})
```

returns all entries where the lightswitch field is toggled off *and* entries that don't have the lightswitch field.

Not a solution for my text field need, but similar enough that it may be useful for other people.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do that at query level without adding the field to your other sections but you can do (although it's not very economical):

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.all() %}

{% for entry in entries %}
{% if entry.text is empty %}
    {{ entry.title }} <br>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yeah that's what pretty much what I'm doing — looping through all the results to build a new array. But like you said it's costly